# Getting rid of extra spaces I have in different rows of a column in datafram

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate through the rows of my column (item_2) and get rid of the extra spaces each row has by using

```
" ".join(x.split())
```

But I get

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

error when running following code.

```
for row in dffirst2[['item_2']].itertuples():
    row.item_2 = " ".join(row.item_2.split())
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example with your code and data

Answer (score 0):

If there's no leading/trailing whitespace, you can just use `.str.replace(r' +',r' ')`

e.g, `dffirst['item_2']=dffirst['item_2'].str.replace(r' +',r' ')`.

If there is, you'll need to toss on a .strip() or use a slightly better regex.